# change CustomViewController fields from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to ios(android dev)

I'm handling opening my app from url, and i got the url in current method in my `AppDelegate`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    NSLog(@"Calling Application Bundle ID: %@", sourceApplication);
    NSLog(@"URL scheme:%@", [url scheme]);
    NSLog(@"URL query: %@", [url query]);

    return YES;
}
```

There are certain params in my link which i'd like to use to fill the `textField` of my `LoginViewController`.

Can i communicate with `LoginViewController` from `AppDelegate`? consider that `LoginViewController` already didLoad.

Answer (score 1):

You can define one property let’s say strName in `appDelegate`.

Then you have to assign it’s value from this method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    NSLog(@"Calling Application Bundle ID: %@", sourceApplication);
    NSLog(@"URL scheme:%@", [url scheme]);
    NSLog(@"URL query: %@", [url query]);

    //for example
    self.strName = [url query];

    return YES;
}
```

Now you can access this property from anywhere.

Create Instance of `appDelegate` In your `viewController`

`#define AppDel ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)`

Then assign as below

```
textfield.text = AppDel.strName;
```

Comment: the problem is that ViewController is loaded earlier then method openUrl is called, so i cant't do it in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate with your controller in several ways:

1. Hold instance in appDelegate and call methods.
2. Save your data in some sort of storage (UserDefault for ex.) and extract in in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods.
3. Use your own observer pattern implementation or `NotificationCenter`